# Is there a configuration for El Cap 'Find Your Cursor' to work for vertical shakes?

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad, cursor

As one of the [El Cap features, Apple touts:](https://www.apple.com/osx/all-features/)

> **Find your cursor**
>
> Rapidly shake your finger on the surface of your trackpad to increase the size of the pointer so it’s easy to spot. You can also shake your mouse to enlarge the pointer.

I find that I place my right hand to the right of the trackpad and use my index finger and when I try to perform a "shake" there is a much larger vertical component to the action. I thought this new feature wasn't even turned on because my shake never made the cursor grow in size.

However, I adjusted my hand position and made the shake much more horizontal and I see the special effect. The problem is this is an unnatural position for me to use the trackpad.

Is there a way to toggle how much horizontal or vertical components are required for a shake to trigger the cursor size to grow?

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to disable this feature, found in System Preferences > Accessibility > Display.

[image]

I translate "back and forth" as being horizontal movement only. There are no options for adjusting the sensitivity, or for registering vertical movement.